# Fastify basic-auth request body is always empty

Tags: node.js, fastify

I'm using the basic-auth plugin in Fastify and it's working fine but for some reason, I can't access the request body as it's always empty. I'm trying to validate something based on username, password and uuid, where the uuid is contained within the request body.

The data is there in the body as if I don't try and include the uuid in this code, the code works absolutely fine.

This is what my code looks like.

**Route file**

```
fastify.post('/transactions', { schema: schema.createTransactionSchema, onRequest: fastify.basicAuth, }, async (req, rep) => {
```

**basic-auth plugin file**

```
import fp from 'fastify-plugin'
import basicAuth from '@fastify/basic-auth'

const plugin = async (fastify, options, done) => {
    const authenticate = { realm: 'api' }

    const validateAuth = async (username, password, req, rep) => {
        console.log(req.body) // Always empty

        const connection = await fastify.mysql.getConnection()
        let rows = []

        try {
            [rows] = await connection.query(
                `SELECT api_key, secret, uuid
                FROM merchants m
                WHERE m.api_key = :username
                AND m.secret = :password
                AND m.uuid = :uuid
                AND m.state = 1`, { username: username, password: password, uuid: req.body.uuid }
            )
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
            throw e
        } finally {
            connection.release()
        } 

        if (rows.length === 0 || username !== rows[0].api_key || password !== rows[0].secret || rows[0].uuid !== req.body.uuid) {
            console.log('hit')
            rep.code(401).send({ message: 'Unauthorized access' })
        }
    }

    fastify.register(basicAuth, { validate: validateAuth, authenticate })

    done()
}

export default fp(plugin)
```

Comment: Could you add the router's schema?

Comment: I've just figured out what the issue is @ManuelSpigolon. When using ```onRequest```, the request body is not available. The Fastify docs state ```Notice: in the onRequest hook, request.body will always be undefined, because the body parsing happens before the preValidation hook.``` I've instead had to use the ```preValidation``` hook. I kept looking at the basic-auth docs and as that contain ```request``` & ```reply``` in the examples, I assumed they would be available.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out why it wasn't working.

When using `onRequest`, the request body is not available. The Fastify docs state `Notice: in the onRequest hook, request.body will always be undefined, because the body parsing happens before the preValidation hook`.

I've instead had to use the `preValidation` hook. I kept looking at the basic-auth docs and as that contains `request` & `reply` with the `onRequest` hook in their examples, I assumed the request body would be available.